# How to do in leaflet if I press a button(control) on the map the method this.map.on('click') shouldn't start working

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How to do in leaflet if I press a button on map and this.map.on('click') starts working. But I don't need it. Only when I press any place on my map this function should work.

I have next code where I create my own button

```
initFitCurrLocationControl(map: L.Map) {
        const container: any = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'currLoc-extract');
        // L.DomUtil.setOpacity( container, 1.0 );
          const extrCurrLocControl = L.Control.extend({
            options: { 
                position: 'topleft'},
            onAdd: (mapp) => {
              container.type = 'button';
              container.title = 'Text';
              container.style.height = '35px';
              container.style.width = '35px';
              container.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
              container.style.borderRadius = '3px';
              container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
              container.style.borderColor = 'rgb(204, 204, 204)';
              container.style.backgroundImage = 
'url(../../../../assets/images/markers/icon-currLoc-32.png)';
              return container;
            },
          });
          map.addControl(new extrCurrLocControl());
          return container;
      }
```

and I have this function

```
this.map.on('click', (evt: any) => {
      console.log('evt: ', evt);
      this.identifySvc.showGetFeatureInfo(this.map, evt.latlng);
    });
```

and now when I press this button, which replaced over map, the last function starts working, but I didn't press on map, I pressed only button

Comment: I solved this issue: added this code "L.DomEvent.addListener(container, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);" before return in .onAdd function